# Does create_autonomy roomba driver package support ROS_Hydro?

Tags: ros, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does [create_autonomy](https://github.com/autonomylab/create_autonomy) driver package support ROS_Hydro?

I'm pleased to see the lasted driver for iRobot_ROOMBA, does this support ROS_Hydro?

If so, Do I need to modify/configure something before compile it for my ROS hydro distribution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234670/does-create_autonomy-roomba-driver-package-support-ros_hydro?/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

create_autonomy does not officially support Hydro. That being said, nothing comes to mind that should stop you from building and running the driver. I believe all of the dependencies have Hydro equivalents. I'd be interested to know what (if any) problems you have if you try to build the driver for Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-05-19**:
thanks! but trying this is not in my work plan~ I'll try this and give you a feedback on an appropriate time  :)

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-12-09**:
@sonictl FYI, http://answers.ros.org/question/249615/python-error-when-try-autonomy-pack-on-roshydro/?answer=249695#post-id-249695